# JQuery syntax error for init

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I'm getting a syntax error on my var url line but I can't seem to figure out
what or why it is, help appreciated

```
SW.wmode = {
    init: function() {
    $('iframe').each(function()
        var url = $(this).attr("src")
        $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent")
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the opening and closing braces of the function argument to `each`.  Your code should be:

```
SW.wmode = {
    init: function() {
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("src")
        $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent")
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: that was it, thanks Dan waiting the obligatory 8 looong minutes to accept.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing semicolons after each line's expression, and some braces.

```
SW.wmode = {
    init: function() {
        $('iframe').each(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr("src");
            $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for additionally correcting the indentation and adding the semi-colon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SW.wmode = {
  init: function() {
  $('iframe').each(function() { //you were missing the brackets
      var url = $(this).attr("src")
      $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent")
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're missing some curly braces... Try running your code through a javascript validator like jshint or jslint to help you catch these things.

Most reasonable text editors will have a plugin that can point out any validation errors on save, so that you don't have to do weird troubleshooting in the browser.. or here! ;)

Here's the valid code:

```
SW.wmode = {
  init: function () {
    $('iframe').each( function() {
      var url = $(this).attr('src');
      $(this).attr('src', url+"?wmode=transparent");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a bit:

```
SW.wmode = {
    init: function () {
        $( 'iframe' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, url ) { 
            return url + '?wmode=transparent';
        });
    }
};
```